# Executing .bat file using Java-script

Tags: javascript, batch-file

Can someone help me in finding a solution for executing a batch file using java-script, i am currently working with nw.js and i tried couple of things which worked for .exe but not for .bat

```
var execFile = require 
('child_process').execFile, child;
child = execFile('C:\\WorkLog\\Software\\abc.exe', //works
//child = execFile('C:\\PDFRotation\\Run.bat', //not working
```

Comment: rather looks like node.js

Comment: @npocmaka nw.js is a JS library to call Node modules from the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

A batch program is not really an executable, so you might have to use `cmd.exe` to invoke the batch file try something like:

```
var spawn = require('child-process').spawn;

spawn('cmd.exe', ['yourfile.bat']);
```

Comment: i tried something like this but this is not working :-

    var spawn =      require('child_process').spawn,child;
    child = spawn('cmd.exe', ['C:\\PDFRotation\\Run.bat']);
    child.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');
    child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    if (/^execvp\(\)/.test(data)) {
    console.log('Failed to start child process.');
    }
    });

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually execute a batch file.  You execute cmd.exe and give it the batch file as a parameter.